# decode the websocket response using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I am trying to create one websocket client code to consume the websocket response data, i am able to connect to ws but response is encoded hence not able to read the response, can someone help me to give some idea to decode this data

```
import json
import pprint
import websocket
from websocket import create_connection

websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = create_connection('wss://ws.dfdw.com/?api_key=kiteeefront&user_id=DESA360&enctoken=6pE685jmJn%2BviKEhegESIBgx%2FvGs9yfXIInAlBTwXMpYkaPZO8losegWBKb4KZym5SKfHfWevS4md1AXFjUW5Gwyn1SjKA%3D%3D&uid=161451687645534')
protocol_str = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
result = ws.recv()
print(result)
print('Result: {}'.format(result))

result = ws.recv()
print('Result: {}'.format(result))

ws.send(json.dumps([json.dumps({'a': 'subscribe', 'v': '[256265,265]'})]))
result = ws.recv()
print(type(result))

print('Result: {}'.format(result))
```

response from the ws and type

```
Result: b'\x00'
<class 'bytes'>
send: b'\x81\xb38\xed\xd3\xdcc\xcf\xa8\x80\x1a\x8c\x8f\xfe\x02\xcd\x8f\xfeK\x98\xb1\xaf[\x9f\xba\xbe]\xb1\xf1\xf0\x18\xb1\xf1\xaad\xcf\xe9\xfcd\xcf\x88\xee\r\xdb\xe1\xea\r\xc1\xe1\xea\r\xb0\x8f\xfeE\xcf\x8e'
```